# Appium Settings starting up but not connecting properly with Appium/Visual Studio?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, android-studio, appium-android

So Im not quite sure what is happening here. I have installed Appium and Android Studio (using Android Studio only for the emulator). I have also installed jdk is installed and `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12` and `ANDROID_HOME: C:\Android` are both set. My example code looks as such:

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
options.PlatformName = "Android";
options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", "10");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86_v10");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"C:\Users\*********\Desktop\***********.apk");
Uri url = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, options);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
// Some example selectors
List<AndroidElement> elements = driver.FindElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText").ToList();
foreach (AndroidElement element in elements)
{
       element.Clear();
       element.SendKeys("Testing Successful");
}
```

I can install the .apk file by just dragging it onto the emulator. I can delete files from the emulator using the adb shell once appium is running. When I run the above code I get the error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms'
```

However I can physically see Appium Settings app opening for a second before closing on the emulator when the above code gets run, and then the error gets thrown. I have tried deleting the io.appium.settings using the adb shell and rerunning the code with no avail (It does seem to reinstall io.appium.settings again properly). Weirdly enough io.appium.uiautomator2.server never gets installed on the emulator (not sure if it should be?). My log for the appium server is as follows:

```
[HTTP] Waiting until the server is closed
[HTTP] Received server close event
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.19.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformVersion":"10","deviceName":"Pixel_3a_API_30_x86_v10","app":"C:\\Users\\*********\\Desktop\\*********","platformName":"Android"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android"}]}}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformVersion":"10","deviceName":"Pixel_3a_API_30_x86_v10","app":"C:\\Users\\*********\\Desktop\\*********.apk","platformName":"Android"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android"}]}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1611198627724 (16:10:27 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time))
[Appium] The following capabilities were provided in the JSONWP desired capabilities that are missing in W3C capabilities: ["automationName","platformVersion","deviceName","app"]
[Appium] Trying to fix W3C capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix:
[BaseDriver]   automationName
[BaseDriver]   platformVersion
[BaseDriver]   deviceName
[BaseDriver]   app
[Appium] Appium v1.19.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.59.0) session
[Appium] Applying relaxed security to 'AndroidUiautomator2Driver' as per server command line argument. All insecure features will be enabled unless explicitly disabled by --deny-insecure
[BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "10",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86_v10",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\*********\\Desktop\\*********.apk",
[BaseDriver]     "platformName": "Android"
[BaseDriver]   },
[BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[BaseDriver]     {}
[BaseDriver]   ]
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: b9c4d8f7-fa3c-48f9-91b3-3d4ef4080f9c
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\*********\Desktop\*********.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Android\adb.exe'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '10.0.0'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Android\adb.exe'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 29
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[ADB] Device API level: 29
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
[AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Package name: '*********'
[ADB] Main activity name: 'crc64fb453ee64b5fe1ef.MainActivity'
[AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: *********/crc64fb453ee64b5fe1ef.MainActivity
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.2.1' >= '3.2.1')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Starting Appium Settings app
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[AndroidDriver] Error: Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms
[AndroidDriver]     at ADB.requireRunningSettingsApp (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\settings-client-commands.js:70:11)
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop *********'
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1611198633596 (16:10:33 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms
[W3C]     at ADB.requireRunningSettingsApp (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\settings-client-commands.js:70:11)
[W3C] Destroying socket connection
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 5874 ms - 659
[HTTP]
```

Furthermore, running the command `pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings` in the adb shell returns the number `4281`

PS. I replaced the user and the application name with *********, these are however all correct in the original log and commands

Comment: Have the same problem in my CI environment, where the emulator runs reeeaaal slooow.
Could the problem be that the settings app does not reach some ready state within 5 sec, and concludes it is dead? I see deviceReadyTimeout with 5sec as default in the capabilities: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Comment: The problem persists with the same message referring to 5000ms after I have increased al timeouts to 1 min.

Comment: The timeout is defined in the appium-adb package. With the current code I see no way to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

This due to the appium settings app is not reacting within 5000ms, probably due to slow machine. The timeout is hardcoded into appium-adb.
A fix is underway: https://github.com/appium/appium-adb/pull/635